# Remove duplicate values based on timestamp

Tags: sql-server

I would need your help with and SQL query that has to remove duplicate entries from a table, mostly using the datestamp column as a criteria in two passes.

*Microsoft SQL DBMS is in question.*

**Here is a little more details:**

***Terminology***: Module is basically a group of single machine workplaces onto which users operate.

***Table***:

ModNam column is fixed, there are 15 modules from M A01 to M A15, then goes the B row M B01 ... M B15 and so on until row F. 
Pos column is irrelevant at the moment.
MdCod column represents a code of the machine being added to the position in the certain module. It can be replaced by another machine at any given time.

I have one query that will be inserting data into this table by copying entries from another table, every time a new machine is added to one of the positions.

Tricky part for me is a second query that should be comparing records in two phases and if:

1) Inside same module (first pass of the query represented with red color in the example pic attached):
ModNam value is the same, MdCod matches between the entries then the most recent datestamp decides the single one to stay and others duplicates get deleted

2) Inside other module (second pass of the query represented with purple color in the example pic attached):
ModNam values are different and MdCod matches between the entries then the most recent datestamp decides the single one to stay and others duplicates get deleted.

Please help and advise.

Example pic (**updated**):

[image]

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Please tag your `DBMS`.

Comment: Timestamps aren't very exact...

Comment: Why does your question mention `ModNum(s)` where there is no such column in your picture?    What do you mean in your second phase by "ModNum(s) are different"?   What is different between the first two purple rows?

Comment: @jarlh - Thank you for contributing my friend. What would be your proposal as an alternative to timestamps? Please share your thoughts. Any piece of advice from SQL gurus is welcome ^_^

Comment: @Tab Alleman - I was referring to the column in terms while in comparison in between iterations. Since the query will be filling the table at different times with sometimes same or similar records.
Yellow colored gradient represents different iterations of the same query that does all the copying, indicated by different time stamp.
Red marked rows represent the rows deleted by the first pass of the query we are trying to construct now, and purple ones second pass of the query.

Comment: In the second pass, why do you say "ModNam values are different", when they are clearly the same in the purple rows?

Comment: @TabAlleman - I was thinking more about M A01 != M B01 in the extension of the table.